PulseAudio not recognizing USB headphones as having surround sound
I've been hammering away at this for the better part of 6 hours, and I'm completely stumped.
I have a Logitech Pro X headset, and having just switched back to Mint from Windows (you're not jamming AI into MY operating system!), I'm trying to get surround sound working on it.
My specs (for quick reference):

Linux Mint 21.3
Kernel version 5.15.0-116-generic
PulseAudio version 15.99
alsa-base version 1.0.25

aplay -lL lists the headset as having surround sound up to 7.1:
hw:CARD=X,DEV=0
    PRO X, USB Audio
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=X,DEV=0
    PRO X, USB Audio
    Hardware device with all software conversions
sysdefault:CARD=X
    PRO X, USB Audio
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=X,DEV=0
    PRO X, USB Audio
    Front output / input
surround21:CARD=X,DEV=0
    PRO X, USB Audio
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=X,DEV=0
    PRO X, USB Audio
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=X,DEV=0
    PRO X, USB Audio
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=X,DEV=0
    PRO X, USB Audio
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=X,DEV=0
    PRO X, USB Audio
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=X,DEV=0
    PRO X, USB Audio
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=X,DEV=0
    PRO X, USB Audio
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
dmix:CARD=X,DEV=0
    PRO X, USB Audio
    Direct sample mixing device
usbstream:CARD=X
    PRO X
    USB Stream Output
a52:CARD=X
    PRO X

pactl, on the other hand:
Card #3
    Name: alsa_card.usb-Logitech_PRO_X_000000000000-00
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Owner Module: 10
    Properties:
        alsa.card = "3"
        alsa.card_name = "PRO X"
        alsa.long_card_name = "Logitech PRO X at usb-0000:0b:00.3-2, full speed"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:0b:00.3-usb-0:2:1.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0b:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.0/sound/card3"
        udev.id = "usb-Logitech_PRO_X_000000000000-00"
        device.bus = "usb"
        device.vendor.id = "046d"
        device.vendor.name = "Logitech, Inc."
        device.product.id = "0aaa"
        device.product.name = "PRO X"
        device.serial = "Logitech_PRO_X_000000000000"
        device.string = "3"
        device.description = "PRO X"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-usb"
    Profiles:
        input:mono-fallback: Mono Input (sinks: 0, sources: 1, priority: 1, available: yes)
        output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 1500, available: yes)
        output:analog-stereo+input:mono-fallback: Analog Stereo Output + Mono Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1501, available: yes)
        output:iec958-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 500, available: yes)
        output:iec958-stereo+input:mono-fallback: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output + Mono Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 501, available: yes)
        off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
    Active Profile: output:analog-stereo+input:mono-fallback
    Ports:
        analog-input-mic: Microphone (type: Mic, priority: 8700, latency offset: 0 usec, availability unknown)
            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
            Part of profile(s): input:mono-fallback, output:analog-stereo+input:mono-fallback, output:iec958-stereo+input:mono-fallback
        analog-output: Analog Output (type: Analog, priority: 9900, latency offset: 0 usec, availability unknown)
            Part of profile(s): output:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:mono-fallback
        iec958-stereo-output: Digital Output (S/PDIF) (type: SPDIF, priority: 0, latency offset: 0 usec, availability unknown)
            Part of profile(s): output:iec958-stereo, output:iec958-stereo+input:mono-fallback

Likewise, alsamixer:

And, finally, speaker-test -D default -c 8 does run, but it's still only running in stereo mode - that is, all of the channels are being smooshed to left, right, or both. speaker-test -D surround71:CARD=X,DEV=0 -c 8 comes back with Broken configuration for playback: no configurations available: Invalid argument.
I've created daemon.conf and default.pa in ~/.config/pulse and modified the default-sample-channels, default-channel-map, and LFE settings, as well as adding load-module module-combine channels=8 channel_map=front-left,front-right,rear-left,rear-right,front-center,lfe,side-left,side-right
(I believe I have that mapping in the right order, but I've tried several - including 5.1 surround - and none have worked.)
Everything I've read thus far indicates that it should work out-of-the-box, and otherwise the above changes would get it working. I even went so far as installing pipewire, but ran into other issues with it that I couldn't quite wrap my head around. I've also looked into dcaenc, but my understanding is that it requires the incoming audio to be formatted using the correct audio codec, which obviously doesn't work for a gaming headset.
Any help would be appreciated - especially if they can shed some light to what's going on under the hood.
Late addition: It appears that aplay also lists my Vive as having 7.1 surround, and PA also refuses to recognize it. Strange.

Your headphones don't have surround ;) It's the windows driver that does!
You only have two ears, so, barring your headphones becoming really clunky, you can't really have a surround system in your headphones themselves. Luckily, you don't have to – the mechanisms that make your brain perceive spatial audio are somewhat well-understood, and can be emulated (Something like: sound comes from far behind? Delay by a while, and make less loud, mix to both headphones and attenuate high frequencies, because the back of your head doesn't conduct these extremely well.).
Logitech says your headphones have "DTS headphone X". That's such a technology! It takes in multiple streams, and calculates them down to a stereo signal that emulates spatial perception quite OK. To do that, someone had to develop the algorithms, and to calibrate the headset (and that's what Dolby earns money with: developing algorithms and formats, and licensing them).
For the technically inclined: you model this (to a first degree) as an impulse response applied to the surround channels to get the summands of the headphone stereo channels.
So, that's a software thing, not a hardware thing. Windows needs some proprietary drivers to do that. On Linux, your default sound system "Pipewire" has Filter Chains that can apply such simulated channels for you. Sadly, I'm not aware of a user-friendly graphical interface to such yet.
You do need some precalculated channels, and armed with these, you can set up a filter chain that does the math to give you surround-effect sound on your headphones. Haven't tried it on pipewire – but here's the Virtual Surround example from the pipewire wiki.

I was afraid of that. I gave the Pipewire wiki a read through, but a lot of the concepts were going over my head - that, and pw-jack kept giving me an error that nothing I found via Google could explain. I suppose that's a topic for another question, though.

That does beg the exact opposite question, though - why is it that aplay reports the sound card having access to a surround sound profile, when ALSA and PulseAudio correctly report only stereo support?

that is an excellent question that I can't answer :(
